# defensive coding practices

Tags: coding-style

Ever since I first wrote

```
if ($a = 5) {
   #  do something with $a, e.g.
   print "$a";
}
```

and went through the normal puzzling session of

- why is the result always true
- why is $a always 5

until I realized, I'd assigned 5 to $a, instead of performing a comparison.

So I decided to write that kind of condition above as

```
 if (5 == $a)
```

in other words:

**always place the constant value to the left side of the comparison operator, resulting in a compilation error, should you forget to add the second "=" sign.**

I tend to call this **defensive coding** and tend to believe it's **a cousin to defensive-programming**, not on the algorithmic scale, but keyword by keyword.

What defensive coding practices have you developed?

---

**One Week Later:**

A big "thank you" to all who answered or might add another answer in the future.

Unfortunately (or rather fortunately!) there is no single correct answer. For that my question was to broad, asking more for opinions or learnings of experience, rather than facts.

Comment: I figured, if I can remember to do that, I can remember the ==  (sadly)

Comment: I dislike the jolt to the normal train of thought; I'm not testing 5, I'm testing $a.  I find it easier if the quantity being tested is listed first.  Maybe I'm a minority - but I don't like the technique, though it is recommended by people I respect.

Comment: It would be better if you couldn't assign anything to variables in if comparison. Java and C# was created, because C++ was full of traps like that. So why this assignment problem still exists?

Comment: @Silvercode: You can still do it in C/C++ because (1) it's consistent, and (2) it doesn't break existing code.

Also, gcc issues warnings if you use assignments in if statements without extra parentheses: if((c = fgetc(file))) (no warning; probably intentional) vs if(c = fgetc(file)) (warning!)

Answer (score 16):

Always use braces:

```
if(boolean)
    oneliner();
nextLineOfCode();
```

is not the same as:

```
if(boolean)
{
    oneliner();
}
nextLineOfCode();
```

If oneliner() is a #defined function, and it isn't defined then your next line of code suddenly becomes subject to the if(). Same thing applies to for loops etc. With braces then the next piece of code never unintentionally becomes conditional on the if/for etc.

Comment: If oneliner() is supposed to be #defined but isn't, then you have a call to an undeclared function (an error in C++, allowed in C).  If oneliner() is #defined with an empty body, then you have a semi-colon giving an empty statement after the if.  In both cases, the constructs are the same.

Answer (score 14):

The top 3 defensive coding practices I employ are

1. unit testing
2. unit testing
3. unit testing

There is no better defense for the quality of your code than a good unit test to back you up.

Comment: But a unit test is something that happens after coding, not during coding. It's a good thing to do, but not a coding practice.

Comment: In my opinion unit testing is a defensive programming practice (an importent one, don't go without!), but not a defensive coding example ... a "opps-ative" coding error in your test is not caught ...  
depends on the (mine really) definitions of "coding" and "programing"

Comment: in many cases a unit test is written before the implementation.

Yes, it is a coding practice.

Comment: It is written before coding (if you do TDD) and applied after coding. Not during coding.

Comment: Whether unit tests are written before or after the actual code is written it has nothing to do with defensive coding/programming but rather ensuring the code produces the correct/expected result given a known set of inputs. They won't help you prevent common coding mistakes as you write the code.

Answer (score 13):

This is a simple and obvious one, but I NEVER EVER NEVER repeat the same string constant twice in my code, cause I KNOW that if I do I will be spelling one of them wrong :) Use constants, people!

Answer (score 8):

Always put curly braces after an if/for/while ... even if there's only one single statement after. BTW D. Crockford thinks it's better too: [Required blocks](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html)

Comment: Perl has mandated curly braces after if (and elsif) and else for aeons.

Comment: Yeah, but Perl also has a unary _ operator, doesn't it?  Don't try and convince me that Perl is a shining beacon of readability :-)

Comment: I just posted a reply on another question pointing out that the "to brace or not to brace" issue is closely related to proper indenting practices.

Comment: Searching Perl's perlop page (http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) yields no mention of a unary _ operator. Care to elaborate on your unfounded claims?

Answer (score 8):

When comparing a string with a constant, write

```
if ("blah".equals(value)){}
```

instead of

```
if (value.equals("blah")){}
```

to prevent a NullPointerException. But this is the only time I use the suggested coding-style (cause "if (a = 1)..." is not possible in Java).

Comment: Just be careful if your programming language does **case sensitivie** string comparisons using the equality operators (or equals method).

Comment: I don't like it since it does not catch null value's, which may or may not be a bug.

Answer (score 7):

One of the things I always try to remember when I am in the Javascript world is to always start the return value of a function on the same line as the return key word.

```
function one(){
    return {
        result:"result"
    };
}

function two(){
    return 
    {
        result:"result"
    };
}
```

These 2 functions will not return the same value.  The first function will return an Object with a property results set to "result".  The second function will return `undefined`.  It's a really simple mistake and it happens because of Javascript's over-zealous Semi-Colon Insertion strategy.  Semi-colons are semi-optional in Javascript and because of this the Javascript engine will add semi-coons where it thinks it's should be.  Because `return` is actually a valid statement a semi-colon will be inserted after the return statement and the rest of the function will essentially be ignored.

Comment: One more reason why Javascript is Evil.

Comment: I very much disagree.  I think it was rushed to the market and didn't have time in a lab for refinement.  The it's populatiry exploded which meant it couldn't be fixed without breaking things.  Used correctly it's a brilliantly adaptive and powerful language. Rant Over.

Answer (score 6):

From my blog:

1. Think positive and return early plus avoid deep nesting. Instead of

   if (value != null) {
       ... do something with value ...
   }
   return

   write

   if (value == null) {
       return
   }
   ... do something with value ...
2. Avoid "string constants" (i.e. the same text in quotes in more than one place). Always define a real constant (with a name and an optional comment what it means) and use that.

Answer (score 5):

- Always initialize variables
- Use `const` wherever I can (without using `mutable`)
- Avoid bare dynamic allocation of memory or other resources
- Always use curly braces
- Code use-cases and tests for any class before coding implementation
- Turn on as many useful warnings as I can (`-Wall -Wextra -ansi -pedantic -Werror` at a minimum)
- Use the simplest tool that solves the problem (in my current environment, that's `bash` -> `grep` -> awk -> Python -> C++).

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I dislike this defensive style, it makes the code hard ro read.

VC compiler warning level 4 will spot this (possible) error.
"warning C4706: assignment within conditional expression"

You can enable just this specific compiler warning, at any level:

```
#pragma warning(3,4706)
```

Comment: GCC will warn you by default when you do this; it advises you to put an assignment inside nested parens to make your intention clear.

Comment: The C# compiler will also complain about this:  Cannot implicitly convert type 'xyz' to 'bool'.

Answer (score 4):

I stopped using languages where you can do

```
if a = 5: print a
```

This has saved me tons of headaches =).

On a more serious note... I now always write the curly braces right after I write my `if`s and `for` loops, and then fill them in afterwards. This makes sure my brackets are always aligned.

Comment: I agree ... but in this not so perfect world, the choice of programming language is not mine...

Answer (score 3):

Returning a copy of a mutable object, i.e. a copy of an array, not the mutable object itself.

Comment: I'd agree, in worlds where speed and memory are not issues.

Comment: Did you guys ever run into problems with a leaking reference?

Comment: +1: An improvement, return an immutable copy whenever possible.  Both are defensive practices - they help prevent defects (ie, stupid programmer tricks ;-))

Comment: I would use const references (e.g. const std::vector<T> &myfunc(...)), as they are faster than copying the object, don't suck up memory, and don't cause side effects due to strange ctors and dtors.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid unnecessary test.
Example

1. if(bool == true)
2. Pointer checks if(pointer)

EDIT:
if(pointer) is not readable so nowadays I prefer if(NULL != pointer)

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly with point 1, but for point 2, I prefer if (pointer != NULL) because it makes the code easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

Couple things:

- Yes, the 1-line blocks.  Use the braces... heck, most good IDE's will make em for you.
- Comment your code after you write it, or re-read your comments if you did it ahead of time.  Make sure your code still does what the comments say.
- Unit testing is a great fallback to re-reading your code.
- Always log an exception... or, NEVER catch an exception without saying so, at least in debug.

Answer (score 1):

Installed Resharper ;)
Then I don't need to write "5 == a" to get warned if I did something wrong :)

Comment: Does that work with perl / python / bash ... 

self discipline does ..  and yes, that's a lame argument in a way .-(

Comment: @lexu: no, but it is a subjective question, and I do not use perl, python or bash :)